# Titanium Vs Adobe Air Vs Phonegap

Tags: cordova, cross-platform, air, titanium

Hi I known there are many answers available for this topic, but they seem to be obsolete as development in all 3 have been immense in a very short span of time. I was analyzing them and finding their comparison as far today. Can somebody plz help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have not considered Air for our application, so this answer compares Titanium and Phonegap.

We ended up choosing Titanium because we were able to build a richer user experience using native controls.  We had an existing Objective-C application and needed to replicate the same native look and feel on multiple platforms (iOS and Android).

We did an initial proof of concept using Phonegap.  The look and feel was more like a web app running in a full-screen browser window.  Even with some rather hairy code we just couldn't make it "feel" like the existing app.

If you do not have this requirement (improve on something which already exists) and have HTML experience, phonegap seems like it would be a good fit for hitting the ground running.  We were able to build the proof of concept very quickly.

Lastly, Titanium quality is really not as far along as I would like, particularly on the Android side.  We had to include multiple workarounds to get the functionality required.  With every SDK release, some of the workarounds broke and new ones needed to be discovered.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap is a big NO for me.
If you need something specific, you need to be go really deep, in order to write your own plug-in.
Performance are poor.
Writing one code that works for web and app it is a lie. You will end up with 2 codes.

Titanium. no idea.

AIR. It is a YES. If you need a rich experience, without a lot of native supports, you will find a comfortable set of tools, really good performance. You will need to code in Actionscript though. The only problem of AIR is Adobe, keep pushing back AIR for PhoneGap. 
So I don't this a good investment, but for sure now it is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium & PhoneGap are having their own pros & cons.
Titanium supports the native environment of the platforms properly develop the standard UI.you can use only What is being provided by Appcelerator.
While PhoneGap creates the Web Apps Where you can implement your own UI & make them customized over native depends on your CSS & Html.
Titanium is much better than the Phone in the sense, maximum development support providing by the Appecelerator, its own Editor available named as titanium Studio(full fledge).
While phoneGap is downloadable plugins.
The Bridge level java Script makes itself easier & portable.
So whatever you chose from these two basically depends upon your project essentials.you must go for the cross checking before initiate the implementation of project selecting one them.must check the possibilities on their authorized portal.it is being a gud procedure to choose one of the technology.